# How should I change my delegation in order to prevent multiple triggering?

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery code which should replace decimal point (Numpad dot) with keyboard point / full stop (keyboard dot), in dynamically added input fields. It works well, when I add the input fields and values one by one. For example, one input field is added, a value entered, and then the user changes cursor position (arrows, click), and types decimal point.

**The problem**

However, the code starts inputing multiple dots at the very end of the value string, whenever I create multiple input fields, populate them (manually) with values, and then try and add dots / decimal points into each of them.

I'm guessing that this happens because of the way I'm delegating, but I'm unsure if that's really the cause, and if it is, how to change it so it always adds as many dots as the user types (usually one, at cursor).

If the delegation isn't the problem, how should I approach this, and what should I change? Using string replace() is not an option.

**Things I've tried**

- Replacing `change` with `focus`, and it still behaved in the same
  way
- Replacing `$('input').keydown(function(e)` with `$(this).keydown(function(e)`, which was slightly better (less dots in the end), but it still created an additional dot at the very end

The snippet below throws back an error (which hides some of the results), but I'm unsure what the error is. For a better display, please see the original [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1wekw8w9/16/).

```js
$('div').on('click', '#remove', removeMe());
$('body').on('change', 'input', function(e) {
    $('input').keydown(function(e) {
        var keyChar = e.keyCode;
        if(keyChar==110) {  // if it's a decimal point
            e.preventDefault();
            var place = $(this)[0].selectionStart; // cursor position
            var newVal = $(this).val().toString().split(""); // converting input to string, then to array
            newVal.splice(place,0,"."); // inserting ".", instead of decimal point 
            newVal = newVal.join(""); // converting it back to a string
            $(this).val(newVal); // setting it as the value - stays a string
        }
        /* keyCode info */
        $('p').append(keyChar+" ");
        /* */
    });
});

$('#add').click(function() {
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    var newInput = $('<input type="text" class="test">');
    parent.append(newInput);
});

function removeMe() {
  $('#remove').on('click', function() {
    var parentDiv = $(this).parent();
    parentDiv.children().remove('input:last-child');
    $('p').empty();
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button id="add">add</button>
  <button id="remove">remove</button>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1wekw8w9/18/)

```
$('body').on('keydown', 'input', function(e) {
  var keyChar = e.keyCode;
  if(keyChar==110) {
     e.preventDefault();

     var start = this.selectionStart;
     var end = this.selectionEnd;
     var val = $(this).val();
     var newVal = val.slice(0, start) + "." + val.slice(end);

     $(this).val(newVal);
  }
});
```

Comment: I can't simply append it, cursor position matters. What if the user types in 35, and later clicks or uses the arrows to position himself between 3 and 5, and _then_ types the dot? That's why I have to convert the value to a string, then to array, then perform array.splice() with the dot, and then join it all to a string. Perhaps there's a better way of doing it, but I'm not seeing it. :(

Comment: This seems to be working. I haven't even thought about using `array.slice()` for this. And it seems that there were more than a few redundancies in my code. Thank you for taking time to help.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
var newVal = $(this).val().toString().split("");
```

with

```
var newVal = $(this).val().toString().split(".");
```

Comment: Hm, but that wouldn't perform the split which I need, since the dot isn't there on the first run. I've tried it, and it just appends the dot at the very end of the input value, while it should put it where the cursor is at the moment of typing, like it does in the original code.